# Sum Values from List when Two Column Values Match

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build something in excel to help with my grocery shopping this year.

I am using some other macros to populate a shopping list from recipes I have found online.

In this shopping list table I would like to try to figure out how to write a macro that would compare the Ingredient and the Measure values from Column A and C and if there are duplicates in the list add the Quantity Values together from the rows into the list.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do in an example:

Original List:

| Ingredient | Quantity | Measure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bacon | 1 |  |
| Garlic | 1 | tablespoons |
| Basil | 1 | tablespoons |
| Butter | 1 | tablespoons |
| Chicken | 1 |  |
| Cayenne Pepper | 1 | tablespoons |
| Garlic | 1 | tablespoons |
| Butter | 1 | tablespoons |

I Want to End up with a List that Looks Like This:

| Ingredient | Quantity | Measure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bacon | 1 |  |
| Garlic | 3 | tablespoons |
| Basil | 1 | tablespoons |
| Butter | 5 | tablespoons |
| Chicken | 1 |  |
| Cayenne Pepper | 1 | tablespoons |

I figured out a way to do this with a Pivot Table but am really struggling on where to start on this in VBA.

Comment: Just curious, in the Original List, is it possible that it has data Butter more than one but different measure ? Example : Butter in cell A6 and cell C6 value "tablespoon". Another Butter appear in cell A10, but the C10 value is "stick".

Comment: Yes that would be possible - in that case I would want to keep it as two separate line items in the list

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, and if it's OK with you that the code using a "helper" column in the same sheet....

Before and after running the macro is something like the image below (please ignore the fill color, as they are used just to make it easier to manually sum of each item):

[image] ===> [image]

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With

With rg.Offset(0, 3)
    .Value = "=concatenate(" & Replace(rg(1, 1).Address, "$", "") & "," & _
        Replace(rg(1, 3).Address, "$", "") & ")"
    .Offset(0, 1).Value = "=sumif(" & .Address & "," & _
        Replace(.Resize(1, 1).Address, "$", "") & "," & .Offset(0, -2).Address & ")"
    .Offset(0, -2).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value
    .Clear
    .Offset(0, 1).Clear
End With

rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count, 3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
        Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

The rg variable is the range of data in column A. It assume that there'll be no blank cell in between of those rows of data in column A.

Then it fill column D with CONCATENATE formula.
Then it fill column E with SUMIF formula.
Then it copy the value in column E to column B.
Then it clear column D and E.
Then it remove duplicate value in the table.

Please note that the code assume there'll be nothing in column D and column E.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with a `SUMIF` formula.

In cell `F5` (Garlic Quantity):

```
=SUMIF(A4:A11,E5,B4:B11)
```

Comment: I don't think this formula would remove the duplicate rows from the list though which is also what I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

If you use a helper column to get the unique identifiers, you can use INDEX(MATCH()) and SUMIF() to generate that list:

Helper Column: `=A2&C2`

[image]

Unique List of helper column: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(D2:D10000,D2:D10000<>""))`

[image]

Index, Match : `=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($F$2#,$D:$D,0))`

[image]

Sumifs: `=SUMIF($D:$D,$F$2#,$B:$B)`

[image: sadf]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, unfortunately my version of excel does not support the Unique or Filter functions

Comment: Ouch. I use those for everything. They cut down on hours of work. do you have much experience with VBA?

Comment: Second option: pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since you can't use dynamic array formulas, there are a couple options.

**1) Pivot Table, Option 1**
Pivot tables are actually pretty good at this:

[image]
[image]

**2) Pivot Table, Alternate Design**

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks again for the response, I started out with the Pivot Table option and think that is probably what I am going to go with unless I can figure out a way to do it with VBA, which I will try to keep hacking away at

Comment: There is definitely a VBA solution. May I ask why that's your preference in this case?

Comment: Well probably would have helped if I would have provided some more detail about the project as a whole.  I have like 75 recipes, one in each tab of the workbook.
I already wrote some VBA code that will select 6 recipes at random and will then populate the ingredients list from each recipe/tab into one big list.
This is where I started with the question about wondering if I could enhance the vba code that creates the big list to remove duplicates and aggregate the amount of duplicate ingredients.

I figured since I was already doing a bunch of the other stuff in VBA I could just add to it.